# How to fix appearing position of Bottom Sheet Dialog

Tags: android, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

In Android 11, `BottomSheetDialog` (BSD) is appearing like it supposed to, but on older versions its either over `Navigation Bar` or under it. I've attached pictures of my problem, and this is my xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/modal_bottom_sheet_background"
    android:backgroundTint="?attr/backgroundColor"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehaviorvior"
    >
   

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/fab_tabliceID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/layout_container_margin_start_end_16"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/layout_container_margin_start_end_16"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius_15"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp"...
```

this is when I tried to envelop everything in Coordinator Layout, but it didnt work:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/modal_bottom_sheet_background"
                android:backgroundTint="?attr/backgroundColor"
                app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
                <!--android:background="@android:color/transparent"-->
                <!--android:layout_gravity="bottom"-->

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/fab_tabliceID"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/layout_container_margin_start_end_16"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/layout_container_margin_start_end_16"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius_15"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"...
```

Ofcourse, one of the solutions I thought of was to, in code, check for Android version and then, if needed, add bottom margin but that doesn't look like the right way.

[image]